# Links containing a Label tag are not clickable on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility

I've come across an unusual situation with general IE compatibility.

The following link is unclickable in IE, but fine on everything else (I've tried IE8 onwards):

```
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk"><label>text</label></a>
```

Whilst the above doesn't work, swapping the label for a div or a span is fine.

Is there any sensible way to make this style of markup work in IE with minimal changes. I'd like to keep the label tag if at all possible.

Comment: Did you try putting the `<a>` tag inside the `<label>` tag?

Comment: The problem is that we have a translation framework that keys on label elements, replacing their contents with the appropriately translated text. Putting the link inside the label will result in the link being lost as the contents get replaced by the translation. It's because of this framework that I want to keep the current structure.

Comment: The markup is invalid and all bets are off. If you need a quick fix in a situation where the markup cannot be corrected, you should describe the real situation (e.g., whether `label` elements are needed in static markup only or in the DOM too) – probably to a consultant, since this kind of things aren’t really problems shared by many people so that generally useful answers can be provided here.

Comment: is jQuery an option?  If so, I have a suggestion for you.

Comment: jQuery is certainly a possibility :)

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't using a label inside an a tag invalidate the html as a label is interactive content? You'd be better served using a span for this.

Comment: Whilst "don't do that" is a valid answer, I'm coming in at the end of a project and the wider context of the site relies on this structure, so I'm looking to see if there's anything that can be done with it.

Answer (score 4):

Labels are for form elements.  In this context, they are being used incorrectly.  Anyone using a screen reader will be confused by the markup, since upon "seeing" a label they are expecting a corresponding form element.  A `span` element would be better suited, and would work across all browsers with minimal changes, since you're simply changing `<label>` for `<span>`.